# Does the Sony A7 run Android, or if not, is there another way to write applications for it?

Tags: software, sony, android, apps, sony-alpha

I'd like to buy a Sony a7R, probably when its successor arrives this year. I saw **apps** on the a7 in some video, and I would like to ask what apps are they? Is the Sony a7 running **Android**?

Can you develop apps for it? Thank you for your answers. I like to shoot timelapses, so if it is possible to **code** custom apps, I would create a free app for HDR timelapses (if it doesn't exist already).

Comment: Whether it's supported is one thing. How long it takes someone to jailbreak+root it is another. I would bet it'll probably be pretty damn fast.

Answer (score 3):

The latest Sony cameras include an Android subsystem used to run apps from the proprietary Sony PlayMemories Camera App Store (PMCA). We reverse engineered the installation process. This allows you to install custom Android apps on your camera.

https://github.com/ma1co/Sony-PMCA-RE

Comment: Amazing job well done. I am seriously contemplating installing apps through that ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is [a portal](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/), where you can select it as ILCE-7(R). It shows some 20 apps, and one of them (E 9,99) does time lapses.

It is possible to develop in-cam apps too but I can't find a link so quickly. Maybe that requires an account first.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I have not googled enough. This is the link to sony camera dev, 
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

at the bottom of the page is interesting line:

**Sony engineers scan Stack Overflow daily for new questions.**

Comment: I did find that link but do note that that API is not for the in-cam apps.

Comment: I know, seems that they only allow API for wifi access from mobile devices. I'll ask at stackoverflow anyways, but it seems there is no Iphone app yet. Does anyone knows release date of new sony a7r iteration? I'll be very glad to buy it and then do some free apps for it.